# How to set smtplib sending timeout in python 2.4?

Tags: python, python-2.4, smtplib

I'm having problems with smtplib tying up my program when email sending fails, because a timeout is never raised. The server I'm using does not and will never have python greater than 2.4, so I can't make use of the timeout argument to the SMTP constructor in later versions of python.

[Python 2.4's](http://www.python.org/doc/2.4/lib/module-smtplib.html) docs show that the SMTP class does not have the 'timeout' argument:

```
class SMTP([host[, port[, local_hostname]]])
```

So how do I simulate this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(120)
```

will make any socket time out after 2 minutes, unless the specific socket's timeout is changed (and I believe SMTP in Python 2.4 doesn't do the latter).

**Edit**: apparently per OP's comment this breaks TLS, so, plan B...:

What about grabbing 2.6's smtplib source file and backporting it as your own module to your 2.4? Shouldn't be TOO hard... and does support timeout cleanly!-)

See [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/smtplib.py?revision=72835&view=markup)...

Comment: unfortunately this breaks starttls() functionality. my code now gets stuck at the smtp.ehlo() after smtp.starttls()

Comment: OK, next try then -- what about grabbing 2.6's smtplib and backporting it as your own module to your 2.4? Shouldn't be TOO hard... and does support timeout cleanly!-)